# Can't run VBS files in Command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, script, vbscript

In a beginner coding course that wants us to use command prompt to execute various types of files we created in notepad. I have run JavaScript and Python files, but whenever I try to run a VBS file I created:

```
c:\entd261>cscript myscriptl01.vbs
```

Command Prompt responds with

```
Input Error: Can not find script file "c:\entd261\myscriptl01.vbs".
```

All of my files are located in the same folder and when ran have no issue. I have VBSedit software that opens the file just fine, Cmd prompt is the only issue. OS: Windows 10 Home 2004 if that matters.

Comment: Are you sure the filename is correct?  You haven't got **O** instead of 0?  Try **cscript m** then press tab for command line completion

Comment: What happens if, in the same folder, you issue `type myscriptl01.vbs` ?

Comment: Did you try to run the scrip in file explorer?

Comment: Type the full path for the script file like `cscript "C:\MyScripts\VBS\myscriptl01.vbs"` (or wherever it may be)